# Bootstrap Datepicker defaulting to sticky date

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am wondering if anybody has already coded an elegant solution whereby a blank Bootstrap Datepicker uses, by default, a previously selected date from another datepicker element within a DOM/UI (instead of defaulting to today's date with each new instance). Here is my solution so far -- which works -- using jQuery cookies:

```
//multiple elements with class 'DatePicker'
$('.DatePicker').datepicker({autoclose:true}).on('show',function() {

    //getting cookie of last datepicker, if it exists
    lastDate = $.cookie('lastDate') ? new Date($.cookie('lastDate')) : null;

    //checking for blank DP and cookie combo, otherwise today is default
    if ($(this).val() == '' && lastDate) { 

         //adding calendar day to date, as DP 'changeDate' event sets object to previous day 
         lastDate.setDate(lastDate.getDate()+1);

         //overriding today-as-default behavior
         $(this).datepicker('setDate',lastDate).datepicker('update');

    }
}).on('changeDate',function(ev) {

    //getting and setting cookie
    selectedDate = ev.date;
    $.cookie('lastDate',selectedDate);

});
```

Comment: You do realize datepicker has an example for something very similar on their home page, right?

Comment: George PHP: wondering a better way to better way to integrate (or extend) this type of logic into (or from) the object bootstrap-datepicker js code itself, as a switchable option... eg .datepicker({sticky:true})

Comment: Giovanni: the example uses explicit DOM references (#dpd1, #dpd2) and start date and end dates. But I can see how you might see it as related.